# IOS - Rearrange tab hidden behind More Tabin tabcontroller

Tags: ios, toolbar, tabbarcontroller

I have a view controller that is accessed via a tab bar controller. Right now it is number 7  (more than 5) so it is hidden behind the More button in storyboard.  I want to move it to position number 2, the second from the left.  If I could access it, I believe, you can just drag and drop but since I can't access it behind the More tab, I don't know what to do.   I really don't want to delete all the segues as there are quite a lot and I could easily make another mistake in recreating them.

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your storyboard file with a text editor to change the tab order: find the `<scene>` tag of your tab bar controller (there will be a comment with the scene name directly before it). Inside of it, there is a `<connections>` tag which in turn contains `<segue>` tags, each of which ultimately represents one contained controller and one tab. By reordering the `<segue>` tags you can change the order of displayed tabs.